# cookies not saved in browser- Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

**I am try to access login api using axios npm package
this is my api url [http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login'](http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login%27)**

**javascript code**

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email, password
      }, 
    });
    console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.message);
  }
 
};
```

when we used api in postman cookies has been saved and display , but when I used this api using axios not saved in browser.

***login api code***

**create token using jwt**

```
const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE_IN,
  });
};
```

**create signIn token and set cookies using `res.cookie`**

```
const createSignToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  
  const cookieOption = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE_IN*24*60*60*1000),
    httpOnly: true
   
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOption.secure = true;

  res.cookie('jwt',token, cookieOption);
  
   
//remove password from the output 
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};



exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  //if email and password exits
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('please provide email and password', 400));
  }
  //check if user exit and password correct
  // const user=User.find({email:email})
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
  

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('email or password wrong', 401));
  }

  //if everything  ok send token to client
 
  createSignToken(user, 200, res);
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the axios `withCredentials: true` option so it always sends cookies.

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      withCredentials: true,                          // <=== Add this
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email, password
      }, 
    });
    console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.message);
  }
 
};
```

If this doesn't solve it, then probably the cookies don't belong to the `http://127.0.0.1:3000` origin so the browser won't send them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem before and the it was because I was using "localhost" of "127.0.0.1" instead of in the link on the browser, so make sure that your browser link is "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).